# Browser plug-in that creates own Google search in extra window

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have an idea of a Firefox extension with the following function:

We put keywords in GOogle and press search -> the extension creates a second Google search in an extra window with a slight iteration of our original keywords

Hence, we end up with 2 pages of search results

What do you think of possibilites in creating, and what tools could be used?

Thank you for your help!
Alex

Comment: What is the exact problem? Did you already read the extension overview in the documentation?

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I am a beginner, and might delegate the programming to someone else, so I am interested in some directions/techniques I could look into to be able to achieve the outcome described - and also would like to know if it is possible in general